# Unable to forward port on VTR router

Tags: port-forwarding

Get the following message wanting to forward the port 80 of my router to a computer of my LAN `The local ports between 80 and 80 on IP 192.168.0.xx have been added as virtual server already, please try another one`.

Not having already this port open

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://community.virginmedia.com/t5/Networking-and-WiFi/Port-Forwarding-on-Hub-3/td-p/3009940/page/4) forum which was the only one I found on the topic, I had to

1. Remove all ports I already configured
2. Add them one by one in ascending order to avoid the problem something like

   1. port forwarding on 21
   2. port forwarding on 22
   3. port forwarding on 80